# mod_rewrite - can't combine rules

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have 3 rules:

```
  # DEL www. from URL
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

  # DEL /index.php fron URL
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
  RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://some-site.kiev.ua/$1 [R=301,L]

  # ADD / to URL
  RewriteRule  ^([^.]+[^./])$ /$1/  [R=301,L]
```

All the rules work individually, but when you use them at the same time - there is a looping and the site don't open...

Help please to combine them

Comment: On what URL are you getting a loop? Can you post the output of wget?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense to me:

```
# DEL /index.php fron URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://some-site.kiev.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to remove `/index.php` from URLs, you can just use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ $1
```

Also, your first rule adds an extra slash at the beginning of the path. Probably doesn't matter, but still.